# Finding a loop in a directed graph in Python

Tags: python, graph, depth-first-search

I wrote this code to find if a directed graph contains a loop or not. I am pretty new to graphs and I saw some examples on the internet but couldn't actually understand their implementations. So I read somewhere that you can colour mark the nodes. So this is my iterative implementation of that method. Is it an okay'ish' approach and how can I improve on it if it's correct?

These are the [test cases](https://algocoding.files.wordpress.com/2015/04/directed_graphs_all_in_one.png)

```
def dfs(graph, start):
    color = {i : 'white' for i in graph}
    stack = [start]
    visited = []

    while stack:
        vertex = stack.pop()
        if color[vertex] == 'grey':
            return True
        color[vertex] = 'grey'
        visited.append(vertex)
        stack.extend((graph[vertex]))
        if  len(graph[vertex]) == 0:
            color[vertex] = 'black'
    return False

def cycle_exists(graph):
    for vertex in graph:
         if(dfs(graph, vertex)):
             return True
    return False



# connected graph with cycle
graph1 = { 0 : [1, 2],
           1 : [],
           2 : [3],
           3 : [4],
           4 : [2] }
assert(cycle_exists(graph1) == True)
print("Graph1 has a cycle.")

#----------------------------------------------------

# disconnected graph with cycle
graph2 = { 0 : [],
           1 : [2],
           2 : [],
           3 : [4],
           4 : [5],
           5 : [3] }
assert(cycle_exists(graph2) == True)
print("Graph2 has a cycle.")

#----------------------------------------------------

# disconnected graph without a cycle
graph3 = { 0 : [],
           1 : [],
           2 : [],
           3 : [] }
assert(cycle_exists(graph3) == False)
print("Graph3 has no cycle.")

#----------------------------------------------------

# disconnected graph without a cycle
graph4 = { 0 : [1, 2],
           1 : [3, 4],
           2 : [],
           3 : [],
           4 : [],
           5 : [6, 7],
           6 : [],
           7 : [] }
assert(cycle_exists(graph4) == False)
print("Graph4 has no cycle.")

#----------------------------------------------------

# If assert raises an error, then a test case was not passed.
print("\nAlgorithm passed all test cases")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets first review your code, and then introduce you to one alternative on how to do unit tests in Python.

- *Adding comments or docstrings is good* – In `dfs()`, not the best named function by the way, you use colors to mark something, but you don't explain what the different colors mean. I had to guess that:

  - `white` means unvisited vertex
  - `grey` means visited vertex
  - `black` means disconnected vertex

  I should have to guess that, and it should be written in a docstring related to the function. This applies for all similar coded segments where it is not intuitive what the variable, function or variable values means.
- *Add blank lines to enhance readability* – The common guidelines says two blank lines between functions, but I would like to extend that to have a blank line around most `if`, `for` and `while` blocks, and the occasional block of code.

  You've done this to some extent, but there are two places I really would like to do this and that *after* the `while` and `for` loop where you do an immmediate `return` statement, which now seems connected to the inner loop code.
- *Avoid loose code at top level* – In general only imports, constants, functions and classes are to be at the top level of your file. This makes it, amongst others, easy to use your file as a module, and it helps organise your code. In your code all of your tests are at the top level, and should have been within some test scope. I'll come back to this below.

  In general you could/should put all this code within one or more functions, like `main()`, and call it from the following top level code at the end of your file:

  ```
  if __name__ == '__main__':
      main()
  ```

  Another nice options, when entering the world of unit tests, is to execute the unit tests when you execute the python file directly, and then otherwise use the exposed functions, i.e. `cycle_exists()` and `dfs()`.
- *Remove the `visited` list in `dfs()`* – It seems like you've forgotten to remove the `visited` list in `dfs()`, as it isn't currently used for anything besides being initialised and added to. You don't do any checks against it.
- *Similarily, remove `black` from the palette* – In your current implementation you don't use the color black for anything, and as such it can be removed, which also would allow for a simpler dict, as the only thing you seem to be interested in is whether it has been visited or not. This can be achieved using a boolean.
- *Add more error handling* – Your code doesn't do much error handling or validation of input, which some like and some don't like. I think I would have added at least a test that the graph exists at some level.
- *No need for the inner parentheses in `dfs()` when adding to stack* – At least in my tests you can remove the inner set of parentheses, and no change happens.

### Refactored code

Here is my refactored code, renaming `dfs()` to `detect_cycle()` and adding some comments and docstrings:

```
def detect_cycle(graph, start):
    """Traverse the graph, and see if we come back to a earlier visited vertex."""

    if graph is None:
        raise ValueError("We need a graph to detect cycles in")

    # Set all vertexes to None, as we don't know the status of it
    visited = {v : False for v in graph}

    stack = [start]

    # Traverse from start, adding connected nodes to the stack as we go
    while stack:
        vertex = stack.pop()

        # If we hit a vertex we've seen before, it is a cycle
        if visited[vertex]:
            return True

        # Mark this vertex as visited
        visited[vertex] = True

        # Add connected nodes to stack, if any
        stack.extend(graph[vertex])

    # If stack is empty, that means no cycle for this start vertex
    return False


def cycle_exists(graph):
    """Return whether the graph has cycles or not."""

    # Loop through each vertex, and check if it has cycles or not
    for vertex in graph:
         if detect_cycle(graph, vertex):
             return True

    return False
```

One thing I haven't addressed if whether this is the most effective way to check for cycles. In fact I know it isn't as for each vertex we traverse the graph over and over again.

This implies that the current algorithm has an \$O(n^2)\$ complexity, which most likely could be simplified utilising another list of visited vertexes, and instead of looping through all vertexes, one could visit only those not already visited. This is left as an exercise for the reader... :-)

### Unit tests

Multiple options exists for doing unit tests in Python, and it comes down to personal preferences. Here I'll present you for the internal version, namely [unittest](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html), which suffices for this code.

A common pattern for a unit test is the following:

- *Arrange* – Set up all needed variables, you need to execute the test
- *Act* – Execute the actual test
- *Assert* – Assert that the test result are as expected

In your case the tests are rather simple, so I've done some according to this scheme, and for some I've taken a few shortcuts. But even though the tests are simple, do remember to let one test method only test one thing. It is considered an anti-pattern to have multiple actions or asserts in one method.

Using unittest, I find that using a class name like `test__function_to_test` is a nice pattern, although not entirely according to guidelines. This should inherit from `unittest.TestCase` enabling us to easily run the tests using `unittest.main()`, which will run all tests functions starting with `test_`.

So here are your tests, and some more. The following code is added beneath the other code (with exception of import at top):

```
import unittest           # This line on the very top

class test__cycle_exits(unittest.TestCase):
    """ Helper class to test the cycle_exists function

    This class test the main method cycle_exists, which heavily
    depends on the detect_cycle method, to find whether cycles exists
    in the connected graphs.
    """

    def test_connected_graph_with_cycle(self):

        self.assertTrue(cycle_exists({
            0 : [1, 2],
            1 : [],
            2 : [3],
            3 : [4],
            4 : [2]
        }))


    def test_disconnected_graph_with_cycle(self):

        self.assertTrue(cycle_exists({
            0 : [],
            1 : [2],
            2 : [],
            3 : [4],
            4 : [5],
            5 : [3] 
        }))


    def test_empty_graph_without_cycle(self):

        # Arrange
        graph = {
            0 : [],
            1 : [],
            2 : [],
            3 : []
        }       

        # Act
        has_cycle = cycle_exists(graph)

        # Arrange
        self.assertFalse(has_cycle)


    def test_disconnected_graph_without_a_cycle(self):

        self.assertFalse(cycle_exists({
            0 : [1, 2],
            1 : [3, 4],
            2 : [],
            3 : [],
            4 : [],
            5 : [6, 7],
            6 : [],
            7 : []
        }))

    def test_confused_graph_result(self):

        # Arrange
        graph = { 
            0: [1],
            1: [2],
            2: [0]
        }

        # Act
        has_cycle = cycle_exists(graph)

        # Arrange
        self.assertFalse(has_cycle, "Didn't expect cycles for this one! Or did I?") # Dead wrong!!!


class test__detect_cycle(unittest.TestCase):
    """Helper class to test the detect_cycle function.

    Using some simple graphs, test the various parts of this functions
    """

    def test_single_connected_graph(self):
        self.assertTrue(detect_cycle({ 0: [0]}, 0))


    def test_simple_connected_graph(self):
        self.assertTrue(detect_cycle({ 0: [1], 1 : [0]}, 0))


    def test_single_disconnected_graph(self):
        self.assertFalse(detect_cycle({ 0: []}, 0))

    def test_simple_disconnected_graph(self):
        self.assertFalse(detect_cycle({ 0: [1], 1 : []}, 0))


    def test_graph_multiple_connections(self):
        self.assertTrue(detect_cycle({
            0: [1, 2, 3], 
            1: [],
            2: [],
            3: [0]
        }, 0))


    def test_multipaths(self):
        self.assertTrue(detect_cycle({
            0: [1, 2, 3],
            1: [2, 3],
            2: [3],
            3: [0]}, 0))


    def test_nonexistent_start(self):

        # Arrange
        graph = { 0: [1], 1: [0] }

        # Act and Assert an exception
        with self.assertRaises(KeyError):
            detect_cycle(graph, 2)

    def test_nonexistent_graph(self):
        # Arrange
        graph = None

        # Act and Assert an exception
        with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
            detect_cycle(graph, 0)            


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Notice how I tried to give meaningful names to each of the test methods so that it should be understandable what failed if/when they fail. If everything is OK the output would have been:

```
.............
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 13 tests in 0.005s

OK
```

However I've deliberately added a fault, with an message, so the output if you run this code is:

```
F............
======================================================================
FAIL: test_confused_graph_result (__main__.test__cycle_exists)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<filename>", line 118, in test_confused_graph_result
    self.assertFalse(has_cycle, "Didn't expect cycles for this one! Or did I?") # Dead wrong!!!
AssertionError: Didn't expect cycles for this one! Or did I?

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 13 tests in 0.005s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

Notice how the 'dots' have changed to include an `F`, and that the `FAIL:` line names that is was the `test_confused_graph_result()` in the `test__cycle_exists` class which has failed, and you get some details as to what failed.

If the test is well written you should now easily see why it failed, and hopefully understand what went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Algorithm is not correct for directed graphs, but it would work for undirected graphs. Consider a graph like one below. It is acyclic (DAG) but your code will detect a cycle. [Test case here.](https://gist.github.com/arekbulski/fd95148d421d9882e03d)

[image]

The correct approach would be: Two dictionaries are needed, pre and post. When you start processing a vertex (just got to it) mark it in pre. After you finished processing a vertex (just processed its adjacents) mark it in post. When processing adjacent vertices, if you find a vertex marked in pre but not marked in post, you found a cycle.

Comment: Hey, I tried the test case you gave and my program gave the correct answer.

Comment: @Ratul I dont understand why it doesnt fail on previous example I gave. I updated the example, and your code fails now. (You can remove last comment and refer to new one.)